# Why is the direction of my blade and the the direction in which my fruit is sliced are not same?

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions

Basically, from wherever point I slice my fruit, it gets sliced in the same manner. I wrote the following code (from a tutorial) but it is not helping at all.
If I would slice from the top, bottom, left or right, it gets sliced in only one way.

[image: The first image shows a watermelon prefab containing the fruit script]

[image: The second image shows the sliced watermelon prefab]

```
public class fruit: MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject fruitSlicedPrefab;
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "blade")
        {
            Vector3 direction = (col.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
            Instantiate(fruitSlicedPrefab, transform.position, rotation);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your tutorial is the one from Brackeys. I saw the first few minutes of it, and his code was never supposed to cut in the direction of the slice. Slicing meshes (especially with textures) is a very difficult task in unity.

Comment: At least, I think so, because when I saw him playing it, the slices were not in the right direction, so it is at least not accurate.

Comment: Can you link us to a gif or something to see what is happening?

Comment: Yes, it's from Brackeys but my slices look weird as compared to the video. But thanks anyway, I have skipped this part.

Comment: Skipped what part? What do the slices prefabs look like and what does the object this script is attached to look like?

Comment: I posted some screenshots for further clarification, hope it's understandable.

Comment: My current device can’t view images, so I will try to help once I switch devices (about 1.5 - 3.5 hours).

Comment: yeah ok, I am tired anyway lol.